# Does the lift created by a wing change when the slats are deployed?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, viscosity, lift

This is a conceptual question as much as an empirical one, but the question is: Does the lift of a wing change when the slats (or any other leading edge device) are deployed? I am stipulating that the angle of attack $(\alpha)$, freestream dynamic pressure $(q_\infty=\frac{\gamma}{2}p_\infty {M_\infty}^2)$, and wing area $(S)$ remain constant. We know that slats can allow the wing to operate at higher angles of attack, but do they change the lift of the wing at any given angle of attack? I am fairly confident that the answer to this question is no, but I was looking for a more rigorous (and possibly mathematical) explanation.

Comment: Not that this is necessarily off-topic here, but note there are probably lots of experts at http://aviation.stackexchange.com/ who might be more familiar with the situation.

Comment: The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading-edge_slats) page says they increase the lift coefficient at a given AoA and speed.

Comment: @tpg2114 I don't see that, where does it say that? It says that slats allow the wing to operate at higher angles of attack, but that's not what I am asking. I specifically stated that nothing (not AoA, not dynamic pressure, not wing area) is to change. So clearly this does not answer my question.

Comment: The second sentence in the first paragraph "A higher coefficient of lift is produced as a result of angle of attack and speed, so by deploying slats an aircraft can fly at slower speeds, or take off and land in shorter distances"

Comment: I think the wiki article is equivocal at best. It does not explicitly say that the angle of attack remains the same. Can we find another source that is less ambiguous?

Comment: What slats and flaps do is increase the effective camber, or curve angle of the wing. Then the definition of AoA gets a bit fuzzy. What is a chord line that everyone could agree on?

Comment: This is actually not as big a concern as one may be led to believe. What I am stipulating is that the aircraft orientation relative to its velocity vector is unchanged (imagine a static model in a wind-tunnel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most questions related to aerodynamics, Stanford University offers the best information needed to answer this question. The following instructional site (presumably for students) outlines the fundamentals of high-lift devices ([AA241 - High Lift Aerodynamics](http://adg.stanford.edu/aa241/highlift/highliftintro.html)), and includes this highly informative plot of Cl vs AoA for the DC-9-30:

[image]

The image clearly shows that the slats barely modify the lift at a given angle of attack, but do allow the wing the operate at much higher angles before stalling. This is exactly what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking: In [*the lift coefficient vs AoA curve*](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/aoa.html#sec-cl-aoa) do slats/flaps increase the slope of the curve as well as extend it?

[*According to Denker*](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/vdamp.html#sec-flaps-lower-stall) that doesn't appear to be so, although he doesn't specifically distinguish between slats and flaps.

Comment: Although, the added complication is to understand if the wing was separating badly before the slat was deployed. In hat case, obviously the wing will create more lift when the slat is deployed. The thrust of my original question was in conditions when the original wing was NOT operating in separated conditions.